# How to save large text more than 20000 chars in Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So the question is what is the best way to save long text (20000+ chars) in realtime database based app. There is a way to save images as links. Maybe there is a way to save text like that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but 2000 characters is not really all that long.  What is the problem you're trying to avoid?

Comment: What's the problem when saving 20000+ chars in realtime database?

Comment: @AlexMamo the problem is to optimize that process

Comment: Doing some quick math using ASCII as a measuring stick; 1 char = 1 byte, so 20000 chars = 20000 bytes. Divide by 1000 result in 20 kb (that's .02 Mb). Maximum size of a string in a single node is 10 **MB**. Keeping in mind that Firebase Data is UTF-8 encoded, we could multiply that by 4 so a whopping 80k. Are you having an issue storing 20k characters?

Comment: @Jay good point. thanks. Ok so what is the best practice to save huge articles somewhere and with help of realtime save the link to this article and then extract that article to show to the user. So what is the best solution for that?

Comment: Firebase is blisteringly fast and 20,000 isn't huge by Firebase standard. Even a dataset 10x that is still not huge. Let's suppose it's not 20,000 or even 200,000 - say is 2,000,000 = 2Mb. (ignoring encoding for this example). That's still 1/5 of what a node can hold

Comment: I just did a test - uploaded 200,000 characters to a firebase node. Wrote a small app that started a timer before reading and then stopped when done reading that node. Needless to say it was done before I could fully lift my finger off the mouse button. I would suggest proceeding with your app and when you run into a bottleneck or performance issue - loop us in and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay ok. Thank you for your time

Answer (score -1):

You can save large text contents in database as Character Large Objects (CLOBS) or or Binary Large Objects (BLOBS).

It depends what database you're using.  You can also simply just save them as files and only store the metadata in the database.  You can save the file to your servers file system or a more preferable method of using a cloud file storage.

[http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_insert_clob_table_column.htm#targetText=Store%20the%20CLOB%20inside%20the,way%20to%20bulk%20load%20data.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_insert_clob_table_column.htm#targetText=Store%20the%20CLOB%20inside%20the,way%20to%20bulk%20load%20data)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/compare-options-for-storing-blobs-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: thank you. I guess thats something i am looking for. Could you please give me more details of each step. I dont know about the step to save them in a file and second thing how with help of firebase extract info? I appreciate your time